# Counting Permutations with Product Rule

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am working on my homework and I solved this problem and I just wanted someone to double check to see if my answer makes sense.

5.4.3: Lining up club members for a photo.

Ten members of a club are lining up in a row for a photograph. The club has one president, one VP, one secretary, and one treasurer.

(c)
How many ways are there to line up the ten people if the president must be next to the secretary and the VP must be next to the treasurer?

I did 2 * 2 * 8! because the count goes down to 8 after grouping P - S together and T - VP and we have to multiply it by 2 twice because the order of p-s s-p t-
vp vp-t.

Does it make sense? Can somebody help me? thank you!

Comment: Your method works; basically you replace the president and secretary by a single block (labeled), and you replace vp and treasurer by a single (labeled) block. Then you arrange the eight entries (6 people plus two "blocks") in $8!$ ways. Then you have two ways of filling up the "President/Secretary" block with them, and two ways to fill up the "VP/Treasurer" block with the two individuals, giving your count.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: "because I don't trust chat gpt." - Very good (+1 for this)